# StyleCop warning SA1126:PrefixCallsCorrectly on name of class

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, naming-conventions, stylecop

I've seen several answers regarding this warning (*SA1126:PrefixCallsCorrectly*) when using static fields/properties and others just not wanting to use `this.`.  However I'm at a loss in my situation:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name = nameof(MyClass);
}
```

`this`, `base`, etc. are not applicable.  What should I be using?  Or should I just keep ignoring the warning?

Comment: Just supress it with attribute and done.

Comment: In addition, this rule is outdated and not included in StyleCopAnalyzers - see changes here: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/KnownChanges.md

Comment: @Evk, Scrapped the classic StyleCop for this new StyleCopAnalyzers and I'm stuck.  I cannot get the analyzer to recognize the `stylecop.json`.  I added it as an *Additional File* and reloaded the project (restarted VS).  The copyright warning still says `company=PlaceholderCompany`.  *sigh, rough day*

Comment: Switched over to [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) and I'm loving it. Fixed lots of issues extremely quickly using the _code fix_ (and ignores SA1126 by default). However, my original question is not answered, so I'll leave it here until someone from the StyleCop community has a solution.

Comment: @reasra, which version of StyleCop were you using? Maybe it didn't support C# 6 and it thought that `nameof()` was a function.

Comment: @vyrp, Interesting possibility. Unfortunately I switched over to the Analyzer version almost a year ago. I don't remember which version I was using, but I'm sure I got it through NuGet. It would have been the latest released version in May 2016.

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name = $"{nameof(MyClass)}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unload the project and edit its `.csproj`, where you can find the StyleCop targets import line. Something similar to this -

```
Import Project = "ProgramFiles\MSBuild\StyleCop\v4.7\StyleCop.targets"
```

And comment this line out. Worked for me !!